# Trailer music on The Force Awakens Soundtrack

Tags: star-wars, the-force-awakens, music

In the final trailer, we can hear at 1:05 Han and Leia’s theme, and at 1:21 Binary sunset (or The Force) Theme. Both are re-edited (re-scored) editions.

The soundtrack from the movie has been released, but I can’t find these two versions of the music. Are they publicly available? Can someone help me find them?

Comment: Is there a rule that the trailer must use only the exact film's soundtrack? Or are they allowed to borrow from any work that they have a license to (which, presumably, they do have a license to, meaning soundtracks from 1-6)

Comment: [trailers don't even have to use music from the same franchise](http://www.pajiba.com/seriously_random_lists/five-soundtrack-scores-commonly-recycled-in-another-films-trailers.php), much less from the actual movie/soundtrack.

Comment: I don't say that there's a rule, but the soundtrack is different if the trailer from the original. I just want to know, if they are going to release this particular version! Because it's awesome!

Comment: @DVK The trailers for Episodes 5, 6, 1-3, all used pre-existing Star Wars music from the soundtracks. For Ep. 7 John Williams composed new music, using new arrangements of old themes, for the first 2 trailers. I imagine he was too busy to do the 3rd one. Also, ≥one of the tv spots has snippets of new Ep. 7 music.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The music for the third trailer is not included on the soundtrack. This is probably because it was not composed by John Williams, though [it *does* feature new arrangements](http://www.slate.com/blogs/browbeat/2015/10/20/star_wars_the_force_awakens_trailer_premiered_new_john_williams_music.html) of themes composed by Williams. John Samuel Hanson and Frederick Lloyd [were among those who composed the music](http://www.slashfilm.com/star-wars-the-force-awakens-trailer-music/) for the trailer.

Here is the music-only version of the trailer:

According to [this article](http://makingstarwars.net/2015/10/official-music-only-version-of-the-new-star-wars-the-force-awakens-trailer/) the [music-only version](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=mBHJpYlz5v0) was released by "Disneyland".

Interestingly, the music for the [first](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=jX1puBHadHc) and [second](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=6GPT5THRSCg) trailers were also not included in the official soundtrack, even though they *were* composed by John Williams. Williams hardly ever includes music he wrote for a movie's trailer(s) in his soundtrack album. The notable exceptions are his soundtracks to [*Harry Potter and the Sorcerer's Stone*](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=a7z8HGXVR80) and *[Hook](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ip-ubq5HwpY)*, both of which have the trailer music at the beginning, entitled "Prologue".